# Value not being passed to UserControl for grid itemsource

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am trying to create a user control within a grid that takes one value and performs an action:

Grid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Grid1" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
            CanUserResizeRows="False" 
            CanUserSortColumns="False" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
            SelectionUnit="Cell" 
            ClipboardCopyMode="None" HeadersVisibility="Column" 
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            Width="1200" Height="150" BorderThickness="0" 
            GridLinesVisibility="None" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
    </DataGrid.Background>
    <DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
        <BindingGroup/>
    </DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserResize="False" 
                                Header="Action Notes" 
                                IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ActionNotes WorkID="{Binding WorkID}">
                    </local:ActionNotes>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

User Control Code:

```
public partial class ActionNotes : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WorkIdDependency = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("WorkID", typeof(int), typeof(ActionNotes));

    public int WorkID
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(WorkIdDependency); }
        set { SetValue(WorkIdDependency, value); }
    }

    public ActionNotes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        MessageBox.Show(this.WorkID.ToString());
    }
}
```

But the MessageBox return WorkID as 0.
I checked the item source, and it is passing the correct values to WorkID.

EDIT:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<DataItem1> test = new List<DataItem1>();
        test.Add(new DataItem1()
        {
            WorkID = 292
        });

        Grid1.ItemsSource = test;
    }
```

Comment: What was the itemsource for Datagrid...

Comment: The itemsource is List<>.  I can iterate through the Grid.Items and I see all the correct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding doesn't occur during the construction of your UserControl so `WorkID` won't be set at that stage, but only later. You can print your message from the `Loaded` event, at which stage the binding should have already happened. Also, you're changing the `DataContext` in your constructor, which is likely to cause problems, so simply remove it. Your constructor should then look like this:

```
public ActionNotes()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show(this.WorkID.ToString());
}
```

One more thing that is likely to cause problems is that your dependency property is not defined correctly. When defining a dependency property you must follow the "PropertyNameProperty" naming convention, and you should also be consistent with your property name (i.e. don't mix `WorkId` with `WorkID`)

So keeping these in mind, your property declaration should look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty WorkIDProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("WorkID", typeof(int), typeof(ActionNotes));

public int WorkID
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(WorkIDProperty); }
    set { SetValue(WorkIDProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think value placed in Dependency property has string value for Integer Datatype that may be an issue.

Comment: I just changed the data type to string.  Now the value is the empty string.

Comment: @Arm0geddon where you have set the ItemsSource?

Comment: The ItemSource is set in the Constructor.  I can see all the values after iterating through Grid.Items after the ItemSource has been set.  The Value just doesn't make it the UserControl.

Comment: Can You upload ur File

Comment: I edited the main post to include itemsource binding.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you calling **MessageBox.Show()** in the constructor of **ActionNotes** for debugging purposes, that you don't intend to leave that in production code. (:>)

Anyway, calling the MessageBox.Show method at the point in the constructor causes a **System.InvalidOperationException** to be thrown.

I believe that this exception is thrown to stop some tricky reentrancy problems with WPF.

Wrap the call to the Show method in **Dispatcher.InvokeAsync** to allow the Dispatcher to work around the issues.  At this point, I'm able to see the WorkID value.

```
 public ActionNotes() {
      InitializeComponent();
      var x = this.WorkID.ToString();
      Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
      {
        MessageBox.Show(this.WorkID.ToString());
      });
}
```

Also, the values for WorkID are haven't been set yet in the constructor.

FWIW, you could debug this without the MessageBox, put a breakpoint in the constructor and evaluate this.WorkID in a Watch Window or Immediate Window.

Also you haven't shown the XAML for ActionNotes.

This bit of XAML is needed to see the value in ActionNotes.

```
<!-- in ActionNotes.xaml -->
```